# Converter invocation when needed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, converters

In my `WPF` app I have a page where are couple of hundreds of textboxes can appear and I have a `MultiValueConverter` applied to all of them. When this page is loading, converter is being called by every `TextBox`. What should I do in order to optimize this? I want to make a `TextBox` to call a converter when this `TextBox` get focus.

Thank you.

Here is code of `Converter`:

```
public class TupleParametersConverter : IMultiValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2) return null;

        var controlName = values[0];
        var measurement = values[1] as Measurement;

        return new Tuple<string, Measurement>(controlName.ToString(), measurement);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is how I use `Converter`:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ConnectToDeviceCommand, ElementName=MainItemControl}">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TupleParametersConverter}">
               <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}" Path="Name"/>
               <Binding />
          </MultiBinding>
       </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
   </i:InvokeCommandAction>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Comment: What is this converter used for?

Comment: to pass parameters as command parameter into viewmodel